# Python 3 Pig Latin Sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

Successfully made a word translator function, and from looking around with what other people have done in my class I know I need to split the sentence argument in the sentence function. But I don't know what to do with it! I've used http://www.mit.edu/~johnp/6.189/solutions/piglatin.py as a reference (it's python 2, however) to help me get to this point, and I understand it, but I get completely lost after list_of_words. Yes, I've looked at the other pig latin questions but I don't think I can comprehend enough to even see what direction I should be going in from here.

Sorry it's a big ask, I don't want you to answer the question, I just want to be pointed in the direction of what to do

```
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"

def pig_latinify_word(word):
    fist_letter = str(word[0])
    if first_letter in consonants:
        return str((word[1:] + word[0] + "ay".lower())) #I think the str() is
    else: return str((word + "way".lower())) #arbitrary, but not sure. Being safe!

def pig_latinify_sentence(sentence):
    list_of_words = sentence.split()
    new_sentence = "" #the bit where I am stuck. Understand up to this point.
    for word in list_of_words:
        new_sentence = new_sentence + pig_latinify_word(word)
        new_sentence = new_sentence + ""
return new_sentence

piglatin = pig_latinify_sentence("This is a about to be a piglatin sentence")
print(piglatin)
```

Sorry if this is just an obnoxious repost, but I have looked at a couple of answers and I don't know what to do from here on. Also, I'd like to add one of my tutors said I didn't need to seperate the consonants, although on the other examples that's all I see. May that have something to do with it? I don't know! Thanks anyway.

Edit: I think I may have found an answer that shows what I need to change from here, but I don't understand. Also being refereed to look up something in my textbook is fine. I just want to read and understand, I'm aware it may be a bit much to ask.

Edit: oh my god, just realized it was a typo. fist_letter, not first_letter.

And thank you! I'll reread your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing when you say:

```
newSentence = ""
```

You are setting the type of `newSentence` as a string so it is easy to understand. Then in the `for` loop, you concatenate the value of the pig latin word to the new sentence, and add a space. I should mention it is good practice to use:

```
newSentence +=  pig_latinify_word(word)
newSentence += " "
```

As it is the same code, it just shortens everything. The same goes for `/=`, `*=`, and `-=`.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you've linked could be rewritten using [`" ".join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [builtin `map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) functions:

```
def pig_latinify_sentence(sentence):
    return " ".join(map(pig_latinify_word, sentence.split()))
```

To take into account a punctuation inside a sentence, you could [use `re` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22776429/4279).