# Converting a sentence to pig latin?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a sentence to pig latin but I can;t get it to work.

Conditions:
1. If it starts with a vowel, add way to the word (e.g eagle become eagleway)
2. If it starts with a consonant, check the second character and so on for as long as it's a consonant, keep checking and strip it out and put it at the end. (e.g grain becomes aingr)

Here is my code so far:

```
x = "The apple is extremely tasty. Great!"
y = x.split()
for i in y:
    if(i[0] == "a" or i[0]=="e" or i[0]=="i" or i[0]=="o" or i[0]=="u"):
        print(i+"way", end = " ")
```

I managed to do part 1. but I can't figure out part 2. I don't understand how to go through the chars and strip the whole part.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can split each work `i` which will return a list of letters in the word. Once you have a list of letters, you can do adding and removing to complete part 2.

Comment: @Cyber I see but how would I implement this? Should it be in the for loop? And at the end there is a space, how do I get rid of it?

Comment: I'll just note that your `if` could just be `if i[0] in 'aeiou':` (you could even make that `i[0].lower()` to cater for uppercase letters...)

Comment: @JonClements Thanks. But how do you think I should go about part 2?

Comment: Let me suggest using of [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/index.html) which makes dealing with language easier.

Comment: related: [Pig Latin Translator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22773826/4279). [My answer shows how handle punctuation (or any non-alpha-numeric characters) and how to use `nltk` to take word pronunciations into account](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22776429/4279).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, pick better variable names:

```
sentence = "The apple is extremely tasty. Great!"
words = sentence.split()
for word in words:
```

Secondly, you can simplify your first check:

```
    if word[0] in "aeiou":
        print("{0}way".format(word), end=" ")
```

Finally, you could use `while` and slicing to move characters from the start of the word to the end:

```
    else:
        while word[0] not in "aeiou":
            word = "".join((word[1:], word[0]))
        print(word, end=" ")
```

Note that this still doesn't quite do what you want:

```
eTh appleway isway extremelyway asty.t eat!Gr
```

I will leave dealing with letter cases and punctuation as an exercise; I suggest making everything one case or the other and removing all punctuation before iterating through `words`.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thanks

Comment: What if I want to make the to eXthWAY? I tried to add it in the join function but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Sab you could add the `X` before the `while` loop, then `WAY` when you `print`, as in the starts-with-vowel case.

Comment: -jonrsharpe I managed to get the WAY added but the X doesn't work even when I try it before while loop. I get XTheWAY as output instead of eXThWAY.

Comment: @Sab You appear to be adding `'X'` to the start *instead of* running the `while` loop. It is easiest to add `'X'` to the end *and* run the `while` loop

Comment: Alternatively, if it's *only* for `'The'`, add that as a specific case (`if word == "The": print("eXThWAY")`)

Comment: -jonrsharpe How would I reverse the process. Let's say I had pig latin and wanted to convert it back to normal?

Comment: @Sab this is not a necessarily-reversible process. If there is a vowel at the start and `'way'` at the end, it's easy. But how do you decide how many consonants to move back from the end of `"aingr"`?

Comment: why would you use `"".join((word[1:], word[0]))` instead of `word[1:] + word[:1]`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Comment: @jonrsharpe: `''.join` optimization doesn't make sense when there are only **two** strings.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian feel free to write it how you like; I tend to use `str.join` rather than `+` all the time, rather than mix and match