# Converting a sentence to piglatin in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a program in Python that will convert sentence into [pig Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin). Pig Latin is loosely defined as taking the first letter of each word, putting it at the end of the word, and adding "ay" to the end of each word. I can't figure out how to separate the first letter from each word in the string much less add it to the end.I assume once I get it removed there's a way to concatenate it to the new word then concatenate "ay" as well. I'm extremely lost here. After tons of trial and error This is all I have, and even this doesn't seem to be working right. Any help is much appreciated.

```
def main():        
    sentence = input('Type what you would like translated into pig-latin and press ENTER: ')
    sentence_list = sentence.split()

    for part in sentence_list:
        first_letter = part[0]

main()
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at some of the already-existing questions? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+pig+latin

Comment: related: [Pig Latin Translator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22773826/4279). Especially, look at [`to_piglatin_naive()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22776429/4279)

Comment: I understand that I can reference a word minus the first letter by using a word[1:] for instance. I just can't seem to figure out how to put this info all together.

Comment: I have looked at those yes. The difference in word translation of piglatin makes it so I can't find the correlation to what I'm trying to do. Entirely too new too this I guess?

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the code:**

```
def main():
        lst = ['sh', 'gl', 'ch', 'ph', 'tr', 'br', 'fr', 'bl', 'gr', 'st', 'sl', 'cl', 'pl', 'fl']
        sentence = input('Type what you would like translated into pig-latin and press ENTER: ')
        sentence = sentence.split()
        for k in range(len(sentence)):
                i = sentence[k]
                if i[0] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
                        sentence[k] = i+'ay'
                elif t(i) in lst:
                        sentence[k] = i[2:]+i[:2]+'ay'
                elif i.isalpha() == False:
                        sentence[k] = i
                else:
                        sentence[k] = i[1:]+i[0]+'ay'
        return ' '.join(sentence)

def t(str):
        return str[0]+str[1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
        x = main()
        print(x)
```

**Runs as:**

```
bash-3.2$ python3 pig.py
Type what you would like translated into pig-latin and press ENTER: my gloves are warm
ymay ovesglay areay armway
bash-3.2$
```

This code uses the logic found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick one

```
def main():
    words = str(input("Input Sentence:")).split()
    for word in words:
        print(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay", end = " ")
    print ()

main()
```

A better solution would probably use list comprehension so you could actually use the output, but this does what you asked.

EDIT:
This works for python3.x
If you want it to work for python2 you are going to have a bit more fun. Just add the strings together for each word, then print the result string.

Comment: I'm in Python 3, forgot to say that. Sorry

Comment: drop `str()`. You could use `word[:1]` instead of `word[0]` for symmetry with `word[1:]`. Follow pep-8, don't use spaces around `=` sign for parameters.