# Write a function called pygLatin() that takes a string as its only parameter

Tags: python, string, function

Write a function called pygLatin() that takes a string as its only parameter. You may assume that the string will be a single word, containing at least one letter. Your function should return a new string that represents the pygLatin version of the word. To do this,remove the first letter, add it to the back of the string, and add ”ay” after it. Return this new string.

Example test cases:

```
>>> x = pygLatin("Run")

>>> print(x)
unRay

>>> y = pygLatin("a")

>>> print(y)
aay
```

Comment: you have already an answer to this question. please follow this [so link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177250/converting-a-sentence-to-piglatin-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a sentence to piglatin in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177250/converting-a-sentence-to-piglatin-in-python)