# Write a Python program that requests a word (in lowercase letters) as input and translates the word into Pig Latin

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators

I need to Write a Python program that requests a word (in lowercase letters) as input and translates the word into Pig Latin. 
•   The rules for translating a word into Pig Latin are as follows:
a)  If the word begins with a **vowel**, add way to the end of the word. For instance, else becomes elseway.
b)  If the word begins with a group of **consonants**, move them to the end of the word and add ay. For instance, chip becomes ipchay.

**My current Coding:**

```
word = input("Enter word to translate: ")
#if the 1st letter of a word is "aeiou", add "way" to the end of the word 
if word[0] == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":  
    print(word + "way")
elif word[0] and word[1] == "b" or "c" or "d" or "f" or "g" or "h" or "j" or "k" or "l" or "m" or "n" or "p" or "q" or "r" or "s" or "t" or "v" or "x" or "y" or "z":
    print(word + "ay")
```

It seems that my current coding has some problem as it only displays words with adding "ways" to the end of word regardless of whether the first letter of the word is vowel or consonant. Also, I am not sure how to move the first letter of a word to the end of the word if the it is a group of consonant and do not know how to deal with if the first letter and second letter in the word form consonants like "zh", "ch", etc.

**The expected outcome of this Python program:**
Enter word to translate: else
The word in Pig Latin is elseway.
Enter word to translate: chip
The word in Pig Latin is ipchay.

Comment: Previous example program: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177250/converting-a-sentence-to-piglatin-in-python

Answer (score 0):

The way Python is interpreting your `if` statements isn't the way you're thinking about it.

```
if word[0] == "a" or "e"
```

I think you're thinking of it as:

```
if word[0] == ("a" or "e")
```

but it is actually being processed as

```
if (word[0] == "a") or ("e"):
```

so it doesn't matter what word[0] actually contains, as "e" (or any non-empty string) will always be evaluated as True by Python, so it will always add 'way'.

The easiest way to rewrite the `if` is

```
if word[0] in "aeiou":
```

That will actually check if it's a vowel, by checking if it appears in the string "aeiou"

Answer (score 0):

'or' does not work like you think it does. It sees if what's on the left is True, if it's not, then 'or' sees if what on the right is True. If any of those is True then 'or' returns True, otherwise it returns False. In your code a letter gets cast to a boolean, and that always gives True. So on the right from 'or' there is always True, which means that your first 'if' will always work.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most pythonic answer, but...

When you use elif: you are adding to the first statement which is why it is always adding way to the end

Use elif to address each vowel then an else statement to handle the consonants:

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
consonants = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z']
word = input("Enter word to translate: ")
#if the 1st letter of a word is "aeiou", add "way" to the end of the word 
if word[0] in vowels:
    print(word + "way")

elif word[0] and word[1] in consonants:  
    print(word[2:] + word[0:2] + "ay") 

else:
    print(word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay')
```

Comment: My initial answer didn't take into account two consonants together, this code does.

Comment: was also thinking...if you need to account for three consonants (christopher) the add another elif statement.   elif word[0:3] in consonants:     print(word[3:] + word[0:3] + "ay")

Comment: I have tried your improve code but unfortunately it still didn't take into account two consonants together. For instance, I type "chip" and It still display the wrong output (hipcay) , not ipchay.

Comment: also, if the instructions are to expicitly use lowercase, then your first if statement should be in regards to someone inputing an uppercase letter that returns: all letters need to be lowercase

Comment: I don't know why as I just copy your code but it still displays "hipcay" instead of ipchay. Did you run the code before?

Comment: `word[0:2] in consonants` won't work as it would be specifically looking for 'ch' in the list, which it won't find. Probably the safest way to identify the leading consonants would be to use a for loop to find the location of the first vowel and then move all of the consonants before that.

Comment: yeah, its running fine on my end, the edited code has the vowels and consonants listed out before putting the if/else statements. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: I disagree David Buck, its looking for any combination of the listed consonants, it could be br, qh, cd, any combination of consonants

Comment: I tried to switch the order of the two codes at once (i.e., print(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay") then else print(word[2:] + word[0:2] + "ay") and It works. But it is not a good way if I type another word instead of "chip". For example, type "bamboo" and it turns out to be mboobaay which "ba" are not two consonants.

Comment: ```consonants = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z']
'br' in consonants
Out[8]: False
'qh' in consonants
Out[9]: False
'cd' in consonants
Out[10]: False```

Comment: you would need to add another elif statement where if word[0] in consonants:   print(word[1:] + word[0] + 'ay')

Comment: You are putting the two letters together when searching.... of course its not going to find that... try 'b','r' in consonants its looking for each letter as the combination, not the two letters combined

Comment: if word[0] in vowels:
    print(word + "way")
elif word[0:2] in consonants:
    print(word[2:] + word[0:2] + "ay")
elif word[0] in consonants:
    print(word[1:] + word[0] + "ay")

Comment: Have tried the above code but it does not work. Word "chip" is still "hipcay"

Comment: @JasonRichards As I assume you've realised word[0:2] is the same as 'ch' which is why it did not work as I was explaining earlier. Unfortunately, your new version falls foul of the same error that I explained in my answer. `elif word[0] and word[1] in consonants:  ` is evaluated as `if (word[0]) or (word[1] in consonants)` so now it will always be true, because word[0] is a non-empty string. You could change is to `if word[0] in consonants and word[1] in consonants` but then what about a word like scram which starts with 3 consonants...