# Simple Pig latin

Tags: python

I wanted to code a program that changes the word order: Hello --> elloHay.The input is a string like " Hello World".
However,it doesn't work.
I am thankful for your help.

```
def pig_it(text):
    a = text.split()
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a.map(i[0])
        for i[0] in a:
        t = i[:1]+ i[0] + 'ay'
    a = " ".join(t)
    return i
```

Comment: Why are you returning `i`? `i` is a number from your range. You also seem to be trying to slice it as if it is a string.

Comment: I think what you mean is that you want to reverse the string, i.e., "Hello" becomes "olleH". If that is what you are looking for there are dozens of ways to do it. For a complete answer on the subject see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python

Comment: Sorry,I forgot to tell you .The input is a string consisting of more than one word

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a sentence to piglatin in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177250/converting-a-sentence-to-piglatin-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def pig_it(text):    
    return text[1:len(text)]+text[0]+'ay'
```